# Usefulness of [back-end] and [front-end] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I came across the [back-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-end) and [front-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/front-end) tags today. Honestly, I really don't see any good use for them on our site.

First of all, [back-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-end) is only used in three questions, one of which is closed. Plus, I don't see any real consequence in getting rid of it.

Same argument for the [front-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/front-end) except for the fact that it is used in 26 questions (7 closed). Again, the tag does not really matter in most of the questions.

So what do you say? Get rid of them? Keep them?

**Update:** So [back-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-end) no longer has any questions. What shall we do with [front-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/front-end)? Is it useful? On-topic? Constrictive?

Comment: moreover, back-end and front-end are often _relative_ terms.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed. Those tags seem to be too meta-ish. I've taken the back-end tag off those respective questions, as they didn't add anything.

Answer (score 1):

They're both reasonably common terms in web development shops, so I think there is some value to them.  [front-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/front-end) tends to be more 'important' to distinguish than [back-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-end), but that's a pretty subjective statement upon my part.

I have found the terms very handy when generalizing skillsets and giving others perspective on my work.  In the past, I have coded more on the back-end and have not done as much UI (front-end) work.

At this point, [back-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-end) has been cleared, but I would vote to leave [front-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/front-end) in place.

Answer (score 0):

front-end and back-end mean different things in different contexts. Some examples:

- With a compiler a front-end parses a language, the back-end generates code for a specific machine
- In a web system the front-end might refer to HTML and JavaScript code, back-end refers to PHP/JSP/ASP/... code running on the server
- In a web system the front-end might refer to a server speaking HTTP and being accessible to the user, the back-end refers to system accessed by the front-end (databases, gearman, services being used, ....)

Especially the last two examples show how subjective this is. I'd remove them.